I failed to change the boost library version
In order to use GUDHI, I installed boost c++ libraries, according to the suggestion of this page. I installed boost 1.84.0, 1.71.0, and 1.74.0 successively. Due to the mismatch, the folders of these three versions were directly deleted. Then boost 1.80.0 was installed. To generate the utility GUDHI, I run the command cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ... The error result is as follows.
What should I do? My operating system is Win 11. My compiler is Visual Studio 2022.
PS D:\Program Files (x86)\gudhi-devel\gudhi-devel> cd build/
PS D:\Program Files (x86)\gudhi-devel\gudhi-devel\build> cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.22631.
-- GUDHI version : 3.10.0a1
CMake Error at D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1841 (file):
  file STRINGS file "D:/Program Files
  (x86)/boost_1_84_0/boost_1_84_0/boost/version.hpp" cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/cmake/modules/GUDHI_third_party_libraries.cmake:3 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (include)


CMake Warning at D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1015 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  0.0.0 (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1523 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2134 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  src/cmake/modules/GUDHI_third_party_libraries.cmake:3 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (include)


CMake Warning at D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1015 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  0.0.0 (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1523 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2134 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  src/cmake/modules/GUDHI_third_party_libraries.cmake:3 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (include)


CMake Warning at D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1015 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  0.0.0 (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1523 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2134 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  src/cmake/modules/GUDHI_third_party_libraries.cmake:3 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (include)


CMake Error at src/cmake/modules/GUDHI_third_party_libraries.cmake:7 (message):
  NOTICE: This program requires Boost and will not be compiled.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
PS D:\Program Files (x86)\gudhi-devel\gudhi-devel\build>


Have you tried clearing the CMakeCache.txt? I simply delete my build dir to make sure my configuration changes get picked up
